# Debugging options for VGA card option ROM

Tags: x86, option-rom

What debugging options are available for development of a PCIe VGA card option ROM, which can be used in different x86 boards which contain only the legacy BIOS?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to output debugging prints to a serial port, assuming your board has one. You could also use ITP for more control. If you want to develop on a virtual machine, I believe modern qemu supports VGA PCI pass-through.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Can I use ITP for testing with commercial boards ? For example if I test the legacy option ROM on a board which is not any evaluation board or CRB rather an assembled pc so in that case ITP would be helpful ?

Comment: Here's some information from Intel: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-system-studio-2014-jtag-debugger-supports-more-processor-families does it help? You could probably check on the specific boards you have whether they have this socket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that link you shared contains one example of UEFI debugging, but I am looking for debugging in legacy environment. Also if the commercial board doesn't have an XDP header or  a socketed processor is there any way to connect a debugger in that case ?

Comment: I don't think ITP cares whether you are debugging UEFI, legacy option ROM or an OS. If your board doesn't support this header I don't know other ways to debug except the ones I listed in the answer.